# How can I keep the main content below the sidebar when the sidebar opens?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to keep the main content under the sidebar when I open the sidebar.
But looking at Vuetify's official website, I couldn't find anything that was relevant. What should I do in this case?
It seems that the padding of mainContent is changing when opening the navigation-bar part, is this the cause?

============
app.vue:

```
<template>
      <v-app>
        <Header 
          v-on:leftChange="leftChange"
        ></Header>

        <Left 
          ref="LeftMethod"
        ></Left>

        <Main/>

      </v-app>
    </template>

    <script>
      import Header from "@/components/Header.vue";
      import Footer from "@/components/Footer.vue";
      import Left from "@/components/Left.vue";
      import Main from "@/components/Main.vue";

      export default {
        components:{
          'Header' : Header,
          'Footer' : Footer,
          'Left' : Left,
          'Main' : Main
        },
        methods: {
          leftChange() {
            this.$refs.LeftMethod.changeA();
          },
        }
      }
    </script>
```

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝
Main:

```
<template>
  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid fill-height>
      <div>MainContent</div>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
</template>
```

========
Header:

```
<template>
  <v-app-bar app clipped-left>
    <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="leftChange"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      leftChange: function(){
        this.$emit('leftChange');
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

==============
Left:

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer 
    app
    v-model="a" 
    clipped 
    stateless
  >
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        a: false,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      changeA() {
        this.a = !this.a;
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[It is intended that v-content resizes based on the size of navigation drawers and other app components with the 'app' property.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/)

If you don't want this, don't use the 'app' prop. Instead, depending on your desired effect, you may have to position the navigation drawer (sidebar) yourself. You can easily do this by adding props like 'absolute' or 'temporary', or by placing the drawer in a container component such as v-menu. [You can use the examples provided by Vuetify as an example.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/)